# i want to check timeout response

Tags: tcp, capl

In the case of general TCP communication, there is a procedure to check whether the received data comes within a certain time, but there is no capl api. So I want to add this logic (this code is written in a network module, not a test module)

To explain the code below, if there is no error in `gtTpRxbuffer`, the data is read.
I want to add time related logic to this part.

```
long TcpRecv( dword socket)
{
  int result = 0;
  
   result = TcpReceive( socket, gTcpRxBuffer, elcount( gTcpRxBuffer));
  
  
  if ( 0 != result)
  {
    gIpLastErr = IpGetLastSocketError( socket);

    if ( WSA_IO_PENDING != gIpLastErr)
    {
      IpGetLastSocketErrorAsString( socket, gIpLastErrStr, elcount( gIpLastErrStr));
      
      writelineex( 0, 2, "TcpReceive error (%d): %s", gIpLastErr, gIpLastErrStr);
    }
  }
 else{
  
  sysGetVariableString(sysvar::TCPIP::TcpData,gTcpRxBuffer,elcount(gTcpRxBuffer));
  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: In the above function, I want to add a part to check if the receive buffer is received for a certain period of time.

I want to know if there is a function related to timeout.

Comment: `TcpReceive` will always return immediately. Either with data or with return value "is pending". Later the callback `OnTcpReceive` will be called, either with data or with an error code, i.e. timeout. If you want to check for the receive timing yourself, you can simply use CANoe's simulation-/measurement-time.

Comment: You're right! I know, I need to write a function related to timeout. However, I don't know how to use it because the use case is not enough.

Comment: In addition, the function used in "test node" cannot be used.

Comment: In conclusion, it should be waiting for until to receive data

Comment: Because my code is actually executed before the data is received.

Comment: There is no possibility to „wait“. You have to implement OnTcpReceive together with calling TcpReceive and check for the return codes on both calls